# Travis - Control Which Node Version is used for NPM Installs

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, build-process, travis-ci

I am attempting to install [an npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-pdf) (markdown-pdf) as part of my Travis-CI build which I believe is not compatible with old versions of Node. On my local machine, I am running Node version 0.10.36, and it works here, so I added what I believe to be the accepted way of defining a specific version to the top of my `.travis.yml` file (although I'm not clear on that either). The MCVE version of the full file is below.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- "0.10"
install:
- sudo apt-get install npm
- npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
- sudo npm install -g markdown-pdf
script:
- echo "stuff was installed."
```

At the top of the build log, I see the following, which seems to indicate that my change worked:

```
$ nvm install 0.10
######################################################################## 100.0%
Now using node v0.10.40
$ node --version
v0.10.40
$ npm --version
1.4.28
$ nvm --version
0.23.3
```

However, further down the log, when travis attempts to execute `sudo npm install -g markdown-pdf`, the log reports the following. Notice that it suggests that the package might not be compatible with the version of Node that is installed, and **it claims that I'm using Node v0.6.12**.

```
$ sudo npm install -g markdown-pdf
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/markdown-pdf
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/markdown-pdf
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: markdown-pdf
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/travis/build/ahemmeter/ahemmeter.github.io/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab108.3
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "markdown-pdf"
npm ERR! cwd /home/travis/build/ahemmeter/ahemmeter.github.io
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: markdown-pdf
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/ahemmeter/ahemmeter.github.io/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I think I've provided enough information, but you can also look at the [public build logs for the project](https://travis-ci.org/ahemmeter/ahemmeter.github.io/builds) and the [github repository](https://github.com/ahemmeter/ahemmeter.github.io) it's building.

Have I made a mistake in declaring which version of Node to use? Do I need to (or should I) do something similar for npm, nvm, and markdown-pdf? How can I force npm-install to use the newer version of Node rather than the old one?

Note that I set the repository to download over HTTP instead of HTTPS. When I did that, the error message changed from "failed to fetch from registry: markdown-pdf" to "No compatible version found: markdown-pdf", which seemed like a step in the right direction, so I kept it; however, I mention it here in case there is a possibility that it causes a conflict.

Comment: do i need to use a `package.json` file? this isn't meant to be a node package, i'm just using an npm tool from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify dependencies when using node.js, travis seems to expect a `package.json` file. You can also use this to specify which version of the node package you want to download.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- "0.10"
script:
- echo "stuff was installed."
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name" : "ahemmeter.github.io",
  "version" : "0.0.0",
  "dependencies" : {
    "markdown-pdf" : "5.3.x"
  }
}
```

*Note from OP: This is the answer I found, but If someone posts an answer that does not involve using a `package.json` file (this is just a test suite rather than a package and I don't want to publish it as a package), I'll mark that answer as accepted.*

Comment: I used the answer here and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249044/how-can-i-install-a-specific-node-js-version-on-a-php-container-on-travis-ci