# How can I install a specific node.js version on a PHP container on Travis CI?

Tags: php, node.js, travis-ci

For a Laravel project I use Travis Ci with the language option as PHP. Besides PHP I want to do some Node JS testing. The default installed version of Node JS does not meet my requirements. How can I specify the version of Node JS in my config file?

I have tried the following. But unfortunately, that does not work.

```
language: php

php:
  - '7.0'
  - '7.1'

node_js:
  - '6.10'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In search for an answer to the *same* question I ended up here, and [there](https://web.archive.org/web/20180801024750/http://entulho.fiatjaf.alhur.es/guias/how-to-use-node-along-with-other-language-on-travis-ci/), and this helped me:

```
language: php

php:
  - 7.0
  - 7.1

before_install:
  - nvm install node 
# "node" is an alias for the latest version

install
  - npm install
```

**Note**: Installing this in the `before_install` section as I am installing the actual packages in the `install` section.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks!