# Installing specific node version on R container on travis

Tags: r, node.js, travis-ci, netlify

Because I use the [Netlify CLI tools](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli/) on travis, I need to have a node version above 8 but the [R container](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r) I use only has 6.12 according to the [error message](https://travis-ci.org/lorenzwalthert/blogdown-cactus/jobs/464898151#L1429). I saw that it is possible to specify the node version for [java script projects](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/) and there is an answer for [PHP projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249044/how-can-i-install-a-specific-node-js-version-on-a-php-container-on-travis-ci) here on StackOverflow, but I tried both and they did not work for my case. What is the proper way of installing a specific node version in an arbitrary travis container such that other applications can access it ? Or maybe even better, (how) can I make npm satisfy the minimal version dependency on node when installing the Netlify CLI tools? I have no prior experience with npm. You can find the version history of my `.travis` file [here](https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/blogdown-cactus/commit/0ad732eb6df008b748ea9c957b96df4545d77460).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solution provided by @talves, I figured out I can modify the `before_script` step to install a specific version of node, e.g. 8.14:

```
before_script:
- nvm install 8.14
- npm install -g netlify-cli
- Rscript -e 'blogdown::install_hugo()'
```

As nvm and npm were already installed. To install the latest stable release replace `8.14` with `node` above. That way, I don't need the `.nvmrc` file.

Comment: I personally would target the same version my local node uses and would have it targeted at the time of the container build not only prior the the scripts. This way I am assured I am running a build against a proven compatible version. Your question did ask for a "specific node version".

Answer (score 1):

> To install Netlify CLI, make sure you have Node.js version 8 or higher

Based on the docs for Netlify [here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli/#installation)

#### Quickest solution for Travis

> Optionally, your repository can contain a .nvmrc file in the repository root to specify which single version of Node.js to run your tests against.

The [quote from the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#specifying-nodejs-versions-using-nvmrc) say to add a `.nvmrc` file to your project at the root with the version

`.nvmrc`

```
8.14.0
```

***Note:*** replace the version with the one compatible with your project that meets all requirements. Also, the `.nvmrc` file is only read when `node_js` key in your `.travis.yml` files does not specify a nodejs version.